# Tensorflow 2: Getting Tensor Value

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am switching to TF2 and I just followed this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/quickstart/advanced),
where the train and step functions are defined now as "@tf.function".

How can I print the values of the Tensors y_pred and loss?

```
@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(images)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

    print("train preds: ", y_pred)
    print("train loss: ", loss)

  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(labels, predictions)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` executes in the Python world (not in graph), so it will only print the tensors once while `tf.function` is tracing your function to construct a graph. If you want to print in-graph, use [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/print).